# How to get params from an event vuetify vue js

Tags: vue.js, events, vuetify.js, router, vue-composition-api

I am learning vuetify and vue js and I want to know how to get params when I click on my treeview :

example :

in the console chrome with vue extension I have :
[vue event update:active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUebQ.png)
(this gives me the id of the element in my treeview)

And I want to compare the params in a function to do some actions when I click on an element of my treeview, how can I do that ?

```
 <v-treeview
  v-if="userExists"
  hoverable
  open-on-click
  @update:active="openRoute"
  :items="items"
  activatable>

  </v-treeview>
```

and the function I made

```
function openRoute () {
  const routes = _.map(items, function (item) {
    if (item.name === 'Structure') { // here I want to compare with the id 
      return item.routeName
    }
  })
  const test = routes.toString()
  context.root.$router.push({ name: routes })
}
```

Thank you for you help

Comment: Hello, I find the answer, we just have to add a param in the function, in my case :  function openRoute (id : number)

Comment: Ha ha, exactly what I was going to say, beat me to it by a second, glad you've got it working :)

Comment: if the answer answers your question, you should accept it. Will help future users with a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the parameter to your function. For example:

```js
function openRoute (emitedValue) {
  console.log(emitedValue);
  const routes = _.map(items, function (item) {
    if (item.name === 'Structure') { // here I want to compare with the id 
      return item.routeName
    }
  })
  const test = routes.toString()
  context.root.$router.push({ name: routes })
}
```